Generated rig controls are twisted

Character rig generated has twisted controls while the meta-rig was initially okay.

Metarig is supposed to face you during front view, so that X axis is Left-Right.
To solve rotate 90 degrees on Z axis both Metarig and character, Apply the rotations (Ctrl A), then re-generate the rig.
